# Pandas DataFrame from a dict of ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dictionary

Consider a dictionary like the following:

```
>>> dict_temp = {'a': np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]),
                 'b': np.array([[3,4,5], [2,5,1], [5,3,7]])}
```

How can I build a pandas DataFrame out of this, using a multi-index with level 0 and 1 as follows:

```
level_0 = ['a', 'b']
level_1 = [[0,1], [0,1,2]]
```

I expect the code to build the multi-index levels itself... I don't care about the column names for now.

Appreciate comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `concat`:

```
pd.concat({k:pd.DataFrame(d) for k, d in dict_temp.items()})
```

Output:

```
     0  1  2
a 0  0  1  2
  1  3  4  5
b 0  3  4  5
  1  2  5  1
  2  5  3  7
```